# When you change the sign of the exponent in an exponential function like $e^x$ into $e^{-x}$, what is it called?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

When you change the sign of $x$ in $e^x$ to $e^{-x}$, is it called getting the conjugate even though its not a complex number in the form of $e^{jx}$? I'm just confused some people I talk to refer to it as conjugate because I thought the term was only applicable to complex numbers and I guess binomials where you change the sign of the middle term.

Comment: It looks like reciprocal, although the term is more general.

Comment: Is $x$ real? Then I would say "reciprocal." Perhaps if you could explain exactly what you saw, where you saw it, and other details about the context, someone might be able to explain it.

Comment: The context is in integral calculus, some problems were taught to us by the professor as needing to multiply a conjugate. For example, the integral of (1 / 1 + e^x) dx would need the conjugate of e^x which is e^-x to be multiplied to both the numerator and denominator. Yeah reciprocal is factually correct but in terms of name it just sounds weird especially that you're using the negative exponent form and not the fraction form.

Comment: The root word of "conjugate" is the same root word as in "conjugal", i.e. marriage.  We use the term in math for things that come in natural pairings.

Comment: @AndroidV11: "reciprocal" *does* seem a little weird since you aren't visually flipping a fraction; however, by the time someone reaches integral calculus, the someone should have internalized that negating exponents *is* reciprocation. ... In any case, while "conjugate" typically links pairs of things (often pairs that differ in a sign), and mathematics can be pretty lenient with definitions that serve the particular needs of a discussion, I suspect that few would recognize $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ as "conjugates" without having this usage of the term explained. ... I'd stick with "reciprocal".